# JdbcTemplate delete syntax

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc

Can someone point out any mistake in my following code of Spring Jdbc Template?

When I click delete, the record is not getting deleted and there are no errors showing.

```
public void delete(String id) {
    logger.debug("Deleting existing person");

    // Prepare our SQL statement using Unnamed Parameters style
    String query = "delete from person where id = ?";

    // Assign values to parameters
    Object[] person = new Object[] {id};

    // Delete
    jdbcTemplate.update(query, person);
}
```

Comment: Do you commit the transaction?

Comment: I do not understand what do you mean.Please give me example if possible.Is the above code correct?

Comment: Yes your code looks correct. Possibilities are: there is no such person with id "id" / you're connecting to wrong database / you're running this on a unit test framework which rolls back the transaction on completion

Comment: may be you are missing the schema name. Eg : delete from schemaName.tableName where id = ?

Answer (score 25):

Here is an example. Pay attention:

> Integer id

```
public boolean delete(Integer id){
    String sql = "DELETE FROM organization WHERE id = ?";
    Object[] args = new Object[] {id};

    return jdbcTemplate.update(sql, args) == 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
    public String deleteXXById(String id) {
        String sql = "DELETE FROM VENUE WHERE id =:id?";
        Map<String, Object> paramMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        paramMap.put("id", id);

        Object[] args = new Object[] {id};
        int update = jdbcTemplate.update(sql, paramMap);
        String updatecount = "Failed";
        if (update == 0) {
            updatecount = "Failed";
        } else {
            updatecount = "SUCCESS";
        }
         return updatecount;
    }
```