# Delete with jdcbTemplate it doesn't work?

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

i'm using jdbcTemplate to insert and delete from dataBase.
I have a probleme with delete using parametres, (it work for insert).

My code :

```
String testSql = "DELETE FROM RDWH14.RDDH_SERV WHERE CODE_PRDT=?";
int row =jdbc.update(testSql,"r"); // when i put "r" instead of ? it also work !  
System.out.println(row); // zero, and still present in DB
```

thank you in advance for your responses.

Comment: looks similiar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45111352/1211547

Comment: thank you for your response, but it daoesn' help me.